# I do not understand why my SQL-Query in PHP is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `path` FROM `maps` WHERE `user` LIKE 0 AND `maps`.`id` = 1";

$result= $conn->query($sql2);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['path'];
    }
```

So, my problem is that it does not get into the while loop. The sql query is 100% correct (tested it manually) and $conn exists and is also working as it should.

Comment: Looks like you need to start debugging... Something we cannot do for you, since only you have access to your system and you did not tell us any about that system... So what does your http server's error log file say? And why do you think that query should return any results?

Answer (score -1):

`user LIKE 0` is a little strange because `LIKE` is a string-matching function.

Because MySQL does type coercion (meaning: guess what you want) it does `user LIKE '0'`.  You didn't show any sample records, so it's hard to guess what you mean by this. Fix your query so it makes sense in your application.

Your program *does not get into the while loop* for one of two reasons:

1. an empty result set (query returned no rows).
2. `$conn->query()` kicked back an error.

You want something like this. I used `die` even though it's crude because I don't know how your program handles errors.

```
$result= $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['path'];
    }
} 
else {
    die $conn->error;
}
```